# Trigger Problem

Tags: trigger

I created a trigger on Campaign Member when ever the Status is added to campaign memberautomatically task have to created to sfdc account owner but But in SOQl how can i reterview the Sfdc Account Owner  and how can i asign a task to sfdc account owner

```
trigger TaskAsign on CampaignMember (after insert) 
{
list<task> taskList  = new list<task>();
list<CampaignMember> cmList = [select Id,Status,CampaignMembe__r.CreatedBy from      CampaignMember where ID in :trigger.new];
Database.UpsertResult[] cList = Database.Upsert(cmList,false);
 if(cList!==null)
 {
  for(CampaignMember c1:cmList)
  {
   Task tsk = new Task();
    tsk.OwnerID = c1.CreatedBy;
   // tsk.Subject = 'something'+c1.Description;
    tsk.Body = c1.CampaignMember__r.Country;
    tsk.DueDate = system.today().addDays(14);
    taskList.add(tsk);
  }  

   insert taskList;

  } 


}
```

Comment: First question... does your code compile?

Comment: @dphil  it showing the error in soql query Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship 'CampaignMembe__r' in field path.

Comment: Before you ask this question, you should probably ask another question to help to get your code to compile.  It will throw people off if they are trying to help you for 1 thing but you have other errors first.  Did you add a custom field for campaign members to lookup to other CampaignMembers or do you just not understand how queries work?

Comment: I answered this under the assumption that you don't understand SOQL and the relationships in the database.  Let me know if that isn't what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

To get the account owner of a CampaignMember, your SOQL would want to contain

```
SELECT Id, Status, Contact.Account.OwnerId FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id in :trigger.new
```

(examples and explanations can be found in the [CampaignMember documentation here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm) ^)

and then, when it comes to putting this information into the task, just set the WhatId field in your task record to the AccountId (as you can see in the [Task documentation here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm))

There are a few open assumptions in this answer (such as CampaignMembers attached to leads, not contacts etc. but I have no other context from your question to refine that!

^ FYI the example given in the SF docs under "usage" *doesn't work* as pointed out by dphil below! So ignore that mark up for sure...

Comment: Campaign member has a lookup to Contact, not the other way around.

Comment: huh. Interesting. That is an example based exactly on that given in the documentation on CampaignMember (through the link I provided)

Comment: I actually read through that document.  It does give that example for a **Lead**, but I got the opposite information about **Contact**.  EDIT:  I just checked the relationships in the database... and the example it gives for lead is actually incorrect also.  Salesforce actually does have some poor/incorrect documentation in some places.

Comment: yep! I ran the Lead example in my dev console and it's simply kapput. I've updated my answer to include the same markup as all the other answers are pouring in! I'm sure between them a solution can be derived now.

Comment: I just reported this inaccurate information to Salesforce by the **send feedback** link on the bottom of the page.

Comment: haha! so did I, so did I. Let's not hold our breath though.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want do this only for contact based CM?

```
for(CampaignMember c1 : [SELECT Contact.Account.Owner.Id 
                         FROM      CampaignMember 
                         WHERE ID in :trigger.new]){
    if(c1.ContactId != null && c1.Contact.Account != null){
        //here handle task
    }
}
```

Or to avoid additional query you can create formula field on CM to get Account Owner Id.